# How to return UI Element Cotrol ID From Binding to another Control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I am using  Grid Control Binding some property using another control 
This is my Grid:

```
 <Grid x:Name="NotePanel"   Width="88" Height="47" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Visibility="{Binding Selection, Converter={StaticResource NullObjectToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.Margin>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SelectionInfoToToolLayoutMultiConverter}">
                <Binding Path="Selection"/>
                <Binding ElementName="Elment ID"/>
                <Binding Path="ParentVM.ZoomView"/>                
            </MultiBinding>
        </Grid.Margin>
```

This is dependent Control:

```
         <Border Background="White" BorderThickness="0" x:Name="bdrEpub">
                    <Image x:Name="Img"
               Source="{Binding Path=ImgSource,ElementName=root}"                 
               Width = "{Binding Path=ViewPageWidth}"
               Height = "{Binding Path=ViewPageHeight}"
               SizeChanged="Img_SizeChanged"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Background="White" BorderThickness="x:Name="bdrPdf">
                    <ContentControl  x:Name="CntControlPdf"                                                         
                      Width = "{Binding Path=ViewPageWidth}"
                      Height = "{Binding Path=ViewPageHeight}"  
                      Content="{Binding Path=PDFViewWPFSource,ElementName=root}" >
                    </ContentControl>
                </Border>
```

I have to  bind the control on the condition:-
**Img**,
**CntControlPdf**

I have to bind this element control in :

```
    <Binding ElementName="Elment ID"/>
```

a/c to To Condition
I have to add this element Id on the Page init method.Is it possible to bind this control dynamically
from page init method:

Comment: Must say, welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Asking a good, concise question is definitely an art!

In answer to your question "Is it possible to bind this control dynamically from page init method":

- Generally, bindings are defined entirely in XAML.
- Generally, defining bindings in code behind is not seen as a good architectural decision.
- I am assuming that you are using MVVM. Some people like using code behind. This is a different way of doing things which has its merits, but is less popular.

Comment: thanks contango, You are I have to achive functanility using mvvm approach . but  I have to decide runtime what control got refer to the <Binding ElementName="here may be some image control Id or ContentControl   Id.We have to decide runtime.I ma not able to refer to the xaml code.

Comment: Perhaps try using a Value Converter? See http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html.

Comment: he wan't the control to be a Binding value and not just a source. 
The question is HOW ?